# Score according to 'logos' aspect ratios

Tags: image, algorithm

I am trying to create a function that, given a set of images, will score each of them depending on how likely are they to be a logo.

Logos have a nice aspect ratio, but I fail to see what would be a good approach on scoring them.  I have done this that takes into account how 'square' an image is. But I don't think  logos are exactly going towards squareness:

```
 if image.height > image.width
   image.points = (image.width/image.height) * MAX_POINTS
 else
   image.points = (image.height/image.width) * MAX_POINTS
 end
```

Any good tips on which aspect ratio or relation between height and width should I take in order to 'score' a potential logo? When I say logo, I mean logos of web pages, like http://www.pepsico.com/img/logo.png

Comment: You're unlikely to come up with a very reliable algorithm unless you do something like machine learning and train a classifier by feeding it a bunch of examples of logos.

Comment: I would score wide images higher than tall ones. Very rare that I see a logo taller than wide. Not much to go on, but every little bit helps, no?

Comment: Geobits, I'm already scoring that :) But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use machine learning for this. Instead of thinking up your own rules, which are likely to be biased and based on your own experience, just use some machine learning library to learn the probabilities based on the width and height.

Then you could make it better by also considering the contents of the image itself...

However, I just realised: this is probably not a good approach. It might be better to take into account the HTML that surrounds the image. However, even this might not be very useful, because there are endless ways to create the same web page with different HTML/CSS.

Comment: I take into consideration several things, HTML that surrounds the images is one of them :). I was just trying to figure out a way to also take into account the aspect ratio, but yes, it might be biased...